# How can I use Task.Result in a Continuation with TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSychronizationContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, mvvm, .net-4.0

In a WPF application, I have a button bound to a Command in my view model. The command launches a task to fetch information from a database, then updates some properties.

```cs
//list in vm to be bound to..
List<DataModel.Item> BoundList;
//new command () =>
{
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew<IEnumerable<DataModel.Item>>( () =>
       return datasvc.GetItems();
    );
    t.ContinueWith( t2 => {
       BoundList = t.Result;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSychronizationContext);
}
```

The project reports a build error on `t.Result` when I use the `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` flag, but when it's not there no build errors. Problem is that I get an unresponsive UI.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Call `Task.Run()`.  Or make it actually async so you can avoid background threads entirely.

Comment: I can't use .NET 4.5 in this project, so the Asych/Await stuff isn't available to me.

Comment: I was originally using Task.Factory.StartNew(). See edit.

Comment: Pause the debugger while it's frozen and see what it's doing.

Comment: Turns out I set the bound property to an IEnumerable and the query was performing ON the UI thread as the variable was bound. Changed it to a list and it works fine now. “Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe.” ― Albert Einstein

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't a flag, it is a static method. Also, the t2 is the result of the task, so you don't need to store the original task as a separate variable:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(datasvc.GetItems)
    .ContinueWith( 
        t => 
        {
            BoundList = t.Result;
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSychronizationContext());
```

If you're `Task` object is running in the UI thread (hence freezing it), this could be because you are already running a number of threads in the thread pool. By default, a `Task` will run on a `ThreadPool` thread unless they are all being used.

However, you can inform .NET that it is a long running operation, and it will generally generate additional threads that can stop your UI from freezing.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx) :

> **TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning**
>   Specifies that a task will be a
>   long-running, coarse-grained operation involving fewer, larger
>   components than fine-grained systems. It provides a hint to the
>   TaskScheduler that oversubscription may be warranted. Oversubscription
>   lets you create more threads than the available number of hardware
>   threads.

So, you would change your Task creation to:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(datasvc.GetItems, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
```

Comment: That did it. Now it compiles, but I still get a frozen UI :( Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @MikeCaron How many items does `t.Result` return? If it's returning a large number of items and `BoundList` is bound to the UI, that could make the UI freeze.

Comment: @MikeCaron I added to my answer to hopefully address this.

Comment: Note that the generic argument to `StartNew` should be able to be inferred, rather than manually specified.

Comment: @Servy You're right, I'll update the answer to get rid of it.